# Flask Login errors: Undefined variable 'login_user' // NameError: name 'login_user' is not defined

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I'm trying to use Flask login but running into an issue with calling `login_user()`. VSCode shows this error:

[image: error]

And when I try to run the app. I get this error:

> NameError: name 'login_user' is not defined.

Usually I would think the error is because I didn't import the right module, but I'm pretty sure I have the right one:

```py
from flask_login import LoginManager, current_user, UserMixin
```

I have also used `pip3 install flask-login`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks so much!

Could it be that the import is not working correctly for some reason?

Comment: You also have to import `login_user` also.

Comment: Please go through all these links: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: importing login_user as @ngShravil.py suggested worked for me.